Problemas con Session
Buenos días a todos,
Estoy enfrentando un problema con las sesiones en PHP. Todo funciona correctamente, pero con el paso de los días, la sesión se bloquea. Al ingresar a la aplicación, en el sidebar se muestran los datos del usuario como si la sesión estuviera activa, pero en los iframes aparecen advertencias indicando que no reconoce las variables de la sesión.
La única manera de desbloquear la sesión es eliminando las cookies manualmente. He implementado el siguiente código para intentar borrar las cookies y destruir cualquier rastro de la sesión, pero el problema persiste.
<?php
// Iniciar la sesión si aún no ha sido iniciada
if (session_status() == PHP_SESSION_NONE) {
    session_start();
}
// Limpiar los datos de la sesión en el servidor
$_SESSION = []; // Vaciar el arreglo $_SESSION

// Eliminar la cookie de la sesión
if (ini_get("session.use_cookies")) {
    $params = session_get_cookie_params();
    setcookie(
        session_name(), // Nombre de la cookie (generalmente PHPSESSID)
        '', // Establecer valor vacío
        time() - 3600, // Asignar un tiempo en el pasado para que expire
        $params["path"], // Usar el mismo path que la cookie original
        $params["domain"], // Usar el mismo dominio que la cookie original
        $params["secure"], // Mantener la configuración de HTTPS
        $params["httponly"] // Mantener la configuración de HttpOnly
    );
}
// Destruir la sesión completamente
session_destroy();
// Confirmar al usuario que la sesión y la cookie han sido eliminadas
echo "La cookie PHPSESSID y la sesión han sido eliminadas.";

A pesar de implementar este código, el problema persiste. Agradezco cualquier orientación que puedan brindarme.

session_write_close() Prueba a agregar esto después del session_destroy -> https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php

Por lo que entiendo tienes un sitio con iframes incrustados. Los iframes tienen por default el valor:
SameSite=Strict

para evitar ataques Cross Site Request Forgery (CSRF). Para que ningun sitio con un origen diferente pueda ingresar. Solo tendrias que cambiarlo:
SameSite=None; Secure

Puedes echarle un ojo aqui https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie

Y en el caso de que tambien sea en el sidebar, que la session se queda bloqueada y no inicializa
